# Notification PendingIntent Intent extras are overridden by another notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

When creating a new notification with a new PendingIntent, the extras in its intent override any previous notification's PendingIntent Intent extras.

For example, lets say I create Notification1 with PendingIntent1, which has Intent1 and its extras.

When I create Notification2 with PendingIntent2, which has Intent2 with its own **different** extras, Intent1 will now have the same extras as Intent2.  Why is this happening?  How do I work around this?

Comment: Android is using the same `PendingIntent` for both notifications, which is why `Intent1` and `Intent2` have the same extras. When you create the `PendingIntent` you need to make sure that they are unique so that you don't end up reusing the same `PendingIntent`. There are several ways to make them unique (different ACTION, different DATA, different REQUEST_CODE), unfortunately just having different EXTRAS doesn't make them unique.

Comment: By default ( if no flags are passed prior to send your notifications ) intent2 extras are beaten by intent1's.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

One is to set a different action on the Intent.  So in your example, you could set `Intent1.setAction("Intent1")` and `Intent2.setAction("Intent2")`.  Since the action is different, Android will not override the extras on the intent.

However, there may be a case where you actually need to set a specific action on this intent (i.e. your action corresponds to a specific broadcast receiver).  In this case, the best thing to do is set the request code to something different in each PendingIntent:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
    (int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* requestCode */, intent1, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
    (int) System.currentTimeMillis() /* requestCode */, intent2, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

By setting a new request code on the PendingIntent, Android will not override the extras on each of their corresponding intents.

Comment: Amazing. You save my day. This Answer must be Approved !

Comment: why is this not accepted? You saved my day also, thanks for this!!

Comment: the request code just has to be different. Holly Molly!!

Answer (score 5):

In my case it worked with by using unique notification id each time like below:

```
mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
```

Generate the unique id each by using `(int) System.currentTimeMillis()` and give this to `NotificationManager` object.

Comment: This only prevent notifications from overriding each other (So that the app can show multiple notifications at the same time), but not the pending intent's extra.

Comment: But one could also apply the same idea to the pending intent request code