# How to send multiple broadcasts in the same day? Android/Java

Tags: java, android

I am able to send one broadcast per day, but I'm trying to send more than one per day. It seems like calling the same function over again is writing over the previous broadcast because I'm only receiving the last broadcast. here is the code

```
send(22,38);
send(22,39);
send(22,40);

public void send(int hour, int minute){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    Context context = this;
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

}
```

Comment: Second parameter of `pendingIntent.getBroadcast()` is requestID. Try setting different requsetID for each pendingIntent. [Refer this answer for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24666194)

Comment: Thank you, I changed the line to                                                    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, minute, intent, 0);     since minute is different each time it works great

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Yes it's working, Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :)